# Flutter ColorScheme and Appainter - how to get PrimaryColorLight?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have theme designed in [Appainter](https://appainter.dev/#/). I have access to a lot of colors from this theme using:

```
Theme.of(Get.context!).colorScheme.onError
```

but not every color I can find in color scheme. How to get for example `Primary color light`? Some of colors from appainter is not listed in `colorScheme`
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`primaryColorLight` is not available in `colorScheme`. You can access it directly from theme context

```
Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight
```